# Why can't I select 'Monitor RGB' in Proof Setup of Photoshop or Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, color-profile

I'm trying to get a consistent look between my web and Adobe suite. At the moment, colors are vastly different, being washed out in photoshop and illustrator.

My understanding is I can simply go into **View -> Proof Setup -> Monitor RGB**, then enable **Proof Colors**. Unfortunately 'Monitor RGB' is *greyed out* so I can't select it. What would cause this? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your document is in CMYK mode. To change it to RGB, choose `File → Document Color Mode → RGB Color`.

[image: Document Color Mode]

Are you doing print work? Or designing for the web? If you're designing for the web, [you'll want to have Illustrator and Photoshop set up for web and UI design work](http://bjango.com/articles/photoshop/) — The correct way to set up Illustrator and Photoshop for web and UI design is with all RGB color management disabled (at the very, very least, ensure `Convert to sRGB` is dialled in Save For Web for both apps).

If you're doing RGB photo retouching, then a different strategy is required.

If you're doing print work, then you'll want to use CMYK color mode and may need to talk to your printer about the correct color profile to use, and may also want to calibrate your display.

Comment: You are right! I actually just worked this out - but in Photoshop, I needed to create a new document as it doesn't seem to have a Document Color Mode menu. At the moment I am doing web work but will work in CMYK for printing. Thanks for your answer.